# AJAX update rails variable

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am using an api from a ticker site to get the current price of a ticker. Now what I have done is set the variables like this. The `ticker` is a gem that I have installed which just makes it easy for me to use their api.

```
@buyprice = ticker.buy_price
```

Then in my views section i just put this: `<%= @buy %>`. I wanted to use AJAX to "refresh" the buy price every 10 seconds. Later I will be using odometer to animate it but for now i just need the variable to update.

There is a similar question here: [Jquery update rails variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20179695/jquery-update-rails-variable) but it did it was meant for an internal API not an external one and I cant get it to work. It does work on another part of my site but not this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking for the Rails >=3 equivalent of "periodically call remote" (an old Rails 2 Prototype method). So here: [Rails 3 equivalent for periodically_call_remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661967/rails-3-equivalent-for-periodically-call-remote)